# not able to hit Rest in camel-cxf

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

I am trying to create rest service using camel cxfRs server from this [link](http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html) But When I try to hit using soapUi it shows me "The requested resource is not available" my endpoint is "/customers/gold?active=true" and I tried this one also.
"CxfRsRouterTest/rest/customers/gold?active=true". Here is cxfConfig.xml

```
<jaxrs:server id="restService"
 address="http://localhost:8080/CxfRsRouterTest/rest" staticSubresourceResolution="true">
 <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
 <ref bean="customerService"/>
 </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
 </jaxrs:server> 

 <bean id="jsonProvider" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider"></bean>
 <bean id="customerService" class="com.infy.CustomerService"></bean>


 <cxf:rsServer id="rsServer"
 address="http://localhost:8080/CxfRsRouterTest/route"
 serviceClass="com.infy.CustomerService" 
 loggingFeatureEnabled="true" loggingSizeLimit="20" >
 <cxf:providers>
 <ref bean="jsonProvider"/>
 </cxf:providers>
 </cxf:rsServer>
```

Customer.java

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Customer {
 private String name;
 private String country;
 private String organization;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@XmlElement
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

@XmlElement
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public String getOrganization() {
    return organization;
}
@XmlElement
public void setOrganization(String organization) {
    this.organization = organization;
}
```

This is my service class

```
@POST@Path("/customer/{type}")
    public Response newCustomer(Customer customer,@PathParam("type") String type,@QueryParam("active") @DefaultValue("true") boolean active){
        return null;
    }
```

Response is jxrs response class

I am using tomcat 8 to deploy. please help me out where I am going wrong in this. I just started to learn camel cxf